# Collapse div wont load on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone help me out here? the collapse div does work but when you first load the web page i am having to click the button twice for the contents to show up.

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w2yunpb5/1/

```js
function slide() {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight) === 0) {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#sliding {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="slide();" class="btn btn-primary">READ</button>
<div id="sliding">
  <p>
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: thanks @Gerard, How did you make the code to work within the site?

Comment: when creating the post, you can insert a snippet (separate icon). When creating a snippet, you can insert HTML, CSS and Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the style of the element isn't maxheight === 0.  It's computed style is maxheight of 0, which isn't the same thing.  You can either assign the style to the element, or change your condition to check if the maxheight is 1000.  Either will work.

```js
function slide() {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight) === 0) {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#sliding {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="slide();" class="btn btn-primary">READ</button>
<div id="sliding" style="max-height: 0">
  <p>
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Or

```js
function slide() {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight) !== 1000) {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#sliding {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="slide();" class="btn btn-primary">READ</button>
<div id="sliding">
  <p>
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because when the page first loads the value of `maxHeight` is not set. Hence the first click on the button hides the element. As it's already hidden, it appears to do nothing.

To fix this you need to amend your logic to check that `maxHeight` has a value and that value is not `0`. Try this:

```js
let sliding = document.getElementById('sliding');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  sliding.style.maxHeight = parseInt(sliding.style.maxHeight, 10) !== 1000 ? '1000px' : '0px';
});
```

```css
#sliding {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary">READ</button>
<div id="sliding">
  <p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Note the use of the unobtrusive event handler in the example. Inline event attributes are no longer good practice and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: Ok works but on second click it wont hide the content now?

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake in the logic. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You could see if `maxHeight` is 1000 before settings it.

Look below

```js
function slide() {
  if (parseInt(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight) != 1000) {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
#sliding {
  transition: 0.5s;
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="slide();" class="btn btn-primary">READ</button>
<div id="sliding">
  <p>
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code I can see that max-height is not set when your function first runs:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight);
```

If you reverse the logic and check for 1000px, you'll start to work on one click:

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight) === 1000) {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "0px";
} else {
    document.getElementById("sliding").style.maxHeight = "1000px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like when first time click happened you are setting `0px` as max-height. What you can do, instead of current logic in your `slide()` function, you can simply flip-flop `open` class, and when `open` will be applied you can do `max-height` via separate CSS rule, take a look: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ady1ntqp/